# Sequelize - how to get model from beforeBulkUpdate hook?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, backend, sequelize-hooks

I was working on logging of the changes in my DB through **sequelize hooks** and I ran into an issue. You see, in **instance hooks** you are able to retrieve the model and its name through **instance parameter** like so :

```
sequelize.beforeUpdate(instance, options) => {
    const modelName = get(instance, 'constructor.options.name.singular')
})
```

but in **"bulk hooks"** there is no instance parameter (logically).

So my question is : **How do I retrieve model or name of the model within bulk hooks ?**

Comment: Isn't `this` a model inside any `bulk hooks` (callback shouldn't be an array function, of course)?

Answer (score 1):

Upon reviewing the sequelize [documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/), it can be observed that the `bulkUpdate` and `bulkDestroy` hooks behave differently from the others, as they only have a single parameter, which is `options`, and within this parameter, all necessary information can be found.

**Just to give a few examples: When I set a `beforeBulkUpdate(options)`**

- `options.fields` = array representing the fields that were changed
- `options.model` = name of the model
- `options.attributes` = object representing the fields and values that were changed

And so on, I hope this helps. All information related to the update operation can be found within the options parameter. If you console log it, you can find what you're looking for.